# Search wms layer in Openlayers based on attributes, zoom on it if found

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, geoserver, wms

I'm using Openlayers 2.14 and use WMS fron GeoServer, I was able to extract the info from the layer when it is clicked through `getfeatureinfo` events and using `new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo`. Somewhat like this:
[image]

```
function activateControls(layerName) {
     //get wms feature info start
     infoControls ={
         click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
             url: geoserver_url,
             title: 'Identify features by clicking',
             layers: [layerName],
             queryVisible: true,
             infoFormat:'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
             eventListeners: {
                 getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                     //console.log(event);
                     //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(event.text);
                     //console.log(event.text);
                     //remove pop-ups when selecting others
                     var pops = map.popups;
                     for (var a = 0; a < pops.length; a++) {
                         if (pops.length == 1) {
                             map.removePopup(map.popups[0]);
                         }
                     };
                     map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken",
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        GenPopText(event),
                        null,
                        true
                     ));
                 }
             }
         })
     };
    for (var i in infoControls) {
        infoControls[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
        map.addControl(infoControls[i]);
    }
    infoControls.click.activate();
 }//end of get wms feature info

function showInfo(evt) {
    if (evt.features && evt.features.length) {
         highlightLayer.destroyFeatures();
         highlightLayer.addFeatures(evt.features);
         highlightLayer.redraw();
         //console.log(GenPopText(evt));
    } else {
        console.log(evt.text);
    }
}

function GenPopText(evt){
     var temstr= "<b><i>" + evt.features[0].gml.featureType + "</i></b><br/>";
     for(var key in evt.features[0].attributes){
        temstr += "<b><span class='text-capitalize'>" + key + "</span></b>:" + evt.features[0].attributes[key] + "<br/>";
     }
     return temstr
}
```

I created a function for it because I have several WMS layer.

Now, as what the question implied. I wanted to search the layer based on attributes like its building name as basis and show the pop-up when found and zoom on it.

This is how I want to implement it:

```
 $("#table_brgy").on("click", "tbody tr", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var building_name = $(this).find("td").first().text();
     ....
     activateControls(layerName,building_name)
 });
```

Like this:
[image]

When the table row is clicked it will show the matching building info in pop-up.

I have done my research but I can't seem to make it work:
[LINK 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94164/how-to-zoom-to-wms-layer-after-cql-filter-on-open-layers)

Answer (score 1):

The OGC WMS Standard does NOT support queries based on attributes, it only supports them based on points (possible operations [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#operations)). What you need is a [**WFS Service**](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) and it's **GetFeature** operation.

Sample code: `http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-states.html`

Comment: WFS loads slow compare to WMS and when I used BBOX strategy, it misbehaves when getting its data extent, map turns black. So, I need to use Fixed strategy which gets the data in one request--which makes it slow.

Comment: Of course, WFS will always be slower because it serves Vector data rather than images, but there is no reason to get ALL data in one request, it's madness. You should check the way you set the BBOX parameter, there may be something wrong with projection or units.

Comment: I got your point, actually I need get all the data and display it because there is an option to the user to show all the structures. I have this idea to use WMS then in zooming or locating the structure (which is mainly the problem using WMS) I will use WFS depending on the filter parameter.